# How can I add a Submenu to the WordPress Admin Bar

Tags: php, wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu, admin

I need to add a dropdown menu to Wordpress in the admin bar to include multiple links. What is the best solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was looking for the answer to this question for a while and couldn't find the solution on here so I thought this would help! I found a great blog post and the perfect solution to my question:

http://davidwalsh.name/add-submenu-wordpress-admin-bar

Like adding functionality to your theme and other admin area, the directives will go in your theme's functions.php file.  The code itself should be self explanatory:

```
function create_dwb_menu() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;

    $menu_id = 'dwb';
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(array('id' => $menu_id, 'title' => __('DWB'), 'href' => '/'));
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(array('parent' => $menu_id, 'title' => __('Homepage'), 'id' => 'dwb-home', 'href' => '/', 'meta' => array('target' => '_blank')));
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(array('parent' => $menu_id, 'title' => __('Drafts'), 'id' => 'dwb-drafts', 'href' => 'edit.php?post_status=draft&post_type=post'));
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(array('parent' => $menu_id, 'title' => __('Pending Comments'), 'id' => 'dwb-pending', 'href' => 'edit-comments.php?comment_status=moderated'));
}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'create_dwb_menu', 2000);
```

Setting an id on the parent menu item allows you to use the parent key for submenu items; the rest of the keys are easy to figure out.  With the menu created, you simply need to add the WordPress hook and specificity to add it!