# WordPress Editing the Admin Help Tab

Tags: php, wordpress

Edit: Just adding a screenshot of the part i want to edit for clarity: [screenshot for clarity](http://prntscr.com/8r59dn)

Im trying to create and modify the WordPress backends help tabs at the top right of the screen with my own content, ive tried using the codex but am unsure if i am looking at the correct reference, whether its not working or im not implementing it correctly but nothing changes when i try use it even in its default usage state. This is the reference im using: [codex reference][2]

Edit 2: Found this article on how to edit the text but doesnt seem to work, its just placing the output text and then breaking it, is this code deprecated or am i missing something here, below is a screenshot of what happens and the code used from the site. using index as it seems to be the one for dashboard but changing it has the same effect. [screenshot of how the code outputs](http://prntscr.com/8r59dn)

```
add_action('load-index-new.php','custom_help_page');
add_action('load-index.php','custom_help_page');
function custom_help_page() {
  add_filter('contextual_help','custom_page_help');
}
function custom_page_help($help) {
  // echo $help; // Uncomment if you just want to append your custom Help text to the default Help text
  echo "<h5>Custom Help text</h5>";
  echo "<p> HTML goes here.</p>";
}
```

------ removed old code as it was incorrect for the purpose, above is new one------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>This might help:</strike>

[How can I add a Submenu to the WordPress Admin Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535264/how-can-i-add-a-submenu-to-the-wordpress-admin-bar/30535265#30535265)

[Adjusting the admin toolbar menu](http://easywebdesigntutorials.com/adding-links-in-the-top-admin-toolbar-menu/)

But to add a link, you can:

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'toolbar_link_to_mypage', 999 );

function toolbar_link_to_mypage( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    $args = array(
        'id'    => 'my_page',
        'title' => 'My Page',
        'href'  => 'http://example.com/my-page/',
        'meta'  => array( 'class' => 'my-toolbar-page' )
    );
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args );
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

To change the help tab, this will do the trick:

[Add “Help” Tab to One or All Dashboard Screens](http://keeneyemedia.com/add-help-tab-to-one-or-all-dashboard-screens/)

Comment: Thanks for those, its not exactly what im looking for but it is extremely useful and i will use this for something else. the part i want to edit is this, see screenshot: http://prntscr.com/8r4yie

Comment: I've made an edit to change the contextual help tab. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i was looking for, greatly appreciate it the help.